# How to find "intersection" of two strings?

Tags: macos, applescript, high-sierra

Simple question for all you experts:

String A: "I like cherries, apples, berries"
String B: "I like cherries, apples, berries, cookies"

I would like to find the text **in string B but not String A**(the odd one out)

I am trying to find-> ", cookies"

Is there an AppleScript that can solve this for me?

Comment: That would be the *difference*, not the *intersection*.

Comment: You need to clarify what it is you're really after!

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any other examples or formal criteria for how matching ought to be performed, I've just given an example here of the simplest way to obtain the difference between two strings:

```
    set A to "I like cherries, apples, berries"
    set B to "I like cherries, apples, berries, cookies"


    set the text item delimiters to {null, A}

    return text items of B as text --> ", cookies"
```

This works if one string is contained entirely within (i.e. is a substring of) the other, as was the case with your given strings.  If `string A` were to be `"But I like cherries, apples, berries" or "I like cherries, apples, berries.", the above method will not work.

It also won't work if `string B` contains the word "null" where `string A` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option...

```
set stringA to "I like cherries, apples, berries"
set stringB to "I like cherries, apples, berries, cookies"
set stringACharacters to count of text items of stringA

set oddManOut to text -1 thru (stringACharacters + 1) of stringB
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, while using **AppleScript's** `do shell script` *command*, and `awk`:

```
set strA to "I like cherries, apples, berries"
set strB to "I like cherries, apples, berries, cookies"

do shell script "awk -F" & quoted form of strA & " '{print $2}'<<<" & quoted form of strB
```

When run in **Script Editor**, with **(Events) (Replies)** selected in the **[Event Log]**, it outputs:

```
tell current application
    do shell script "awk -F'I like cherries, apples, berries' '{print $2}'<<<'I like cherries, apples, berries, cookies'"
        --> ", cookies"
end tell

Result:
", cookies"
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways to accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.